# Where can I find documentation on shell script syntax for using a regex within a variable construct?

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression, variable-substitution

I'm debugging a shell script (which I didn't write) that contains this loop:

```
read line < "$pid_file"
for p in $line ; do
  [ -z "${p//[0-9]/}" -a -d "/proc/$p" ] && pid="$pid $p"
done
```

Can someone point me to documentation on using (what I'm assuming) is a regular expression within a string variable construct, i.e. the "${p//[0-9]/}".  This topic isn't easy to narrow down in Google.

Comment: Try running that after `cd /proc` with a `$pid_file` that contains `* 1\ 2=2 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a form of [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) (i.e. variable expansion) with a text transformation of the value of the variable. The value of the variable `p` undergoes the replacement of the pattern `[0-9]` to the empty string wherever it occurs — in other words, `"${p//[0-9]/}"` is the value of `p` without its digit characters.

In the bash documentation, you'll find it under `${parameter/pattern/string}`. This form replaces the first occurrence of the specified pattern with the specified string. If the first slash is doubled, all occurrences are replaced. The pattern is a [glob](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29), i.e. the same wildcard patterns as in filename matching.

Comment: Perfect, that link is exactly what I needed.  THANK YOU!

Comment: So basically, they're testing that p is numeric, and that its /proc/ directory exists.  Correct?

Comment: @Alan Yes, that's it.